# Nunit addon not showing up in the addon list in nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, automated-tests, nunit-2.5

I am having troubles creating an addon for nunit.  I think I have done the necessary steps, but for some reason I do not see my created addon in the nunit tools addon list. I have created a new project in c# and referenced nunit.core and nunit.core.interfaces from my nunit installation directory.  Then I build it and copy over the dll into the addins directory.

Here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Core.Extensibility;
using NUnit.Core;


[NUnitAddinAttribute(Type = ExtensionType.Core, Name = "Test Addin", Description = "A test addin.")]
public class CTestingAddin : IAddin, EventListener
{
    #region IAddin Members

    public bool Install(IExtensionHost host)
    {
        IExtensionPoint listeners = host.GetExtensionPoint("EventListeners");
        if (listeners == null)
            return false;

        listeners.Install(this);
        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region EventListener Members

    public void RunStarted(string name, int testCount)
    {
    }

    public void RunFinished(Exception exception)
    {
    }

    public void RunFinished(TestResult result)
    {
    }

    public void SuiteFinished(TestResult result)
    {
    }

    public void SuiteStarted(TestName testName)
    {
    }

    public void TestFinished(TestResult result)
    {
    }

    public void TestOutput(TestOutput testOutput)
    {
    }

    public void TestStarted(TestName testName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EVENTLISTENER: Test has started");
    }

    public void UnhandledException(Exception exception)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I don't see anything in the addons when I open up nunit.  Any ideas what could keep me from seeing this addon and getting it loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.  Apparently the eventlistener doesn't show up in the addons, I just ran my test and it was running my listener even though it wasn't showing up on the addons.

Comment: I experienced the same. Does anybody know the reason for this or is it a bug?